# How does $1/r$ gravity change in de Sitter space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

Classical $1/r$ gravity arises from general relativity when curvature is neglected and speeds are small compared to the speed of light.

In de Sitter space with a positive cosmological constant $\Lambda$, curvature cannot be neglected, but is small. What happens if one tries to deduce "classical" gravity form general relativity in de Sitter space? How is the $1/r$ expression modified? Is gravity increased or decreased at large distances?

---

Here is a bonus question. If I get it right (please correct/criticize), a positive $\Lambda$ *reduces* the gravitational attraction at large distances, compared to Newtonian gravitation. But many people (Verlinde, Milgrom, etc.) argue that a positive $\Lambda$ *increases* gravitational attraction at large distances. How is such a statement possible? Am I confusing something?

Comment: See the paper by Nowakowski on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0004037

Comment: The paper also shows that $\Lambda$ reduces gravity.